# Error while trying to list dictionary keys error in python, list object not callable?

Tags: python-3.x

```
tel = {'jack':4098, 'sape':4139}
tel['guido'] = 4127
list(tel)
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 list(tel)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

What am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: See, there is nothing wrong in the given code snippet. `['jack', 'sape', 'guido']` is the output from the snippet. You must have created a variable name `list` in your code.

Comment: just delete the `list` value. ie `del list` then run your code

Answer (score 2):

You must've assigned to `list` a different value earlier in your IPython session. Restart your IPython session and the same code would work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had the same trouble in anaconda Python3 environment.